# Error using a yuiConfig object in TreeView

Tags: javascript, yui

I am trying to add a yuiConfig attribute to a list that gets rendered into a TreeView and get `a "j" is undefined error`.

The examples I see add a yuiConfig attribute to leaves. I attempting to do this at a folder level. Is this part of the problem?

The code is messy since I'm doing it in a template, but here's the offending line:

```
    <li yuiConfig='{"type":"DateNode","editable":true}'><span class="folder">${a[0]}</span>
```

The code works without the yuiConfig part at the folder level, and I can add a yuiConfig at the leaf level as well.